# Can I add a run-time dependency to a Clasp project?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ramda.js, clasp

I want to develop some small scripts to enhance a Google Sheet. Clasp allows me to easily develop scripts locally, compile TypeScript and then push them into the Google Script environment. So far, excellent.

I want to use Ramda so that I can do some functional-style programming in my project. Is there a way I can add this and some other dependencies to my project?

What if I wanted to use Jest or some kind of testing library? Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

While I know nothing about Clasp, Ramda is usually supplied as a single-file, dependency-free script.  I would imagine any system that allows multiple files would let you upload -- or at worst paste the contents of -- `ramda.js`.

Have you tried this and run into issues?